# Separate settings for Easy Vim (with -y flag)

Tags: vim

Is there a way to have some settings which will work only for Easy Vim (Vim with `-y` flag, i.e. `vim.exe -y`), but not for "normal" Vim?

This works for me:

```
_vimrc file + _gvimrc file
```

However, this doesn't:

```
_vimrc file + _evimrc file
```

Probably I shouldn't try to use separate file for it, but incorporate such settings into `_vimrc` or `_gvimrc` instead? How is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, this isn't easy, but it's doable:

From within Vimscript (= in your .vimrc), you can call `ps` to get the arguments vim was called with

```
echo split(system("ps -o command= -p " . getpid()))
```

This prints `['vim', '-y']` and you could then go on checking if `-y` is in that list (with `count`) and then do different things depending on that.

---

I see that you're using Windows though, so you have to find an alternative to the `ps` solution. [This answer on superuser](https://superuser.com/a/519802) makes me believe `WMIC path win32_process get Caption,Processid,Commandline` might be a start..

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that those "settings" that break in Easy Vim is `'insertmode'`, as that is the defining option of it. You can check for it in your `~/.vimrc`, like this:

```
if ! &insertmode
    " Stuff that only works in default (non-Easy) Vim.
    " ...
endif
```